# Upsert join of two tables (with 1 to many relationship)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am working with an Oracle DB and needed to perform an Upsert on two tables, but I am struggling with how to do it. Following is a simplified version of the two tables:

- Table 1: Tax Record (Tax Record ID int, Tax Class ID int, Vintage ID
  int)
- Table 2: Tax Control (Tax Book ID int, Tax Record ID int, Tax
  Rate ID int)

Tax Record IDs are unique, but for each tax record Id there can be multiple tax books (number of tax book varies for each tax record).

Now, I need to perform an upsert on these two tables. I will be moving the two tables from one database to another. I planned on using a Merge statement to do this. However the ON condition is where I am having trouble. This is what the rules are for merging:

- Tax records which have the same tax class, vintage AND same tax rate for each of their tax books should merge.

Merging on tax class and vintage isn't an issue. But I can't figure out how do I check the tax rate for each of the tax books. In my programming mind, I know I have to perform something akin to a foreach loop. But I don't know how to translate it into sql commands.

I am allowed to make dummy tables if required. But I want to minimize the number of different queries I have to run. One approach I have, as a backup, is to do the entire thing using PL/SQL. But I will prefer if it can be done through sql as I will have to learn PL/SQL and my colleagues also will in future need and modify this sql. They know SQL but don't know PL/SQL either.

Here is the code so far:

```
Merge INTO tax_record tr
USING (Select * from tax_record@anotherdb, tax_control@anotherdb
  where tax_control@anotherdb.tax_record_id = tax_record@anotherdb.tax_record_id) tc
ON tr.tax_class_id = tax_record@anotherdb.tax_class_id
  AND tr.vintage = tax_record@anotherdb.vintage
  AND ______?______
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (tr.data1, tr.tax_record_id, tr.vintage, tr.tax_class_id)
values (tc.data1, tc.tax_record_id, tr.vintage, tr.tax_class_id)
```

In the ? mark, I want to implement the tax rate per tax book check. That is what I need help with

Comment: Might just be me...but I'm really confused by what you are trying to ask here.  If you are having problems with the 'on' part of the statement, please post the rest of what you have and maybe this question will be more clear as to what your issue is.

Comment: Are you trying to put multiple records into your local `tax_record` table? Or insert records into two local tables? If the latter don't you want two separate merges? Presumably the `&&` is supposed to be `and`; but I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve in the missing `__?__` part.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I am trying to do two separate merges. I just showed one to show part of the code. And yes, sorry && was supposed to mean and. And in the ? part, I have to implement the tax rate part. That is where I check each tax book in the tax control table and see if the tax rate is same for each book. So, for example I have 2 tax records - 1 and 2. For 1, if tax rate is 10% for Federal book and 15% for state book. Then, for the tax record 2, I will merge only if the tax rate is 10% for federal and 15% on state. Only in that case, I will merge the two records as 1 on the local database.